# Show the Background-Color of a DIV with a lower z-index

Tags: html, css

I want to make a part of a DIV (div2) transparent so it shows the background-color of a DIV (div1) that is under the DIV (div2).

http://jsfiddle.net/499nhjb0/2/

```
<br>
<div class="firstDiv" style="z-index:1;" >
    <img src="http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150226/fag7h2u7.png" style="display:block;" width="auto" height="50"/>
</div>

<div class="secondDiv" style="z-index:2; ">
    <img src="http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150226/xmv678we.png" style="display:block;" width="auto" height="50"/>
</div>
<br>
div1 with higher z-index
<br>
<div class="firstDiv" style="z-index:3;" >
    <img src="http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150226/fag7h2u7.png" style="display:block;" width="auto" height="50"/>
</div>

<div class="secondDiv" style="z-index:2; ">
    <img src="http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150226/xmv678we.png" style="display:block;" width="auto" height="50"/>
</div>
<br>
```

The images i use are transparent so the color (div-background) is variable. Currently the peak of image1 looks like its not from image1.
I want that it looks like this:
[image: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150226/45r27i57.png]

I have created two types of images you can see in the fiddle.

Do you have an idea how to solve the problem? I can change the transparency images if you have an idea. The images can be different.

Comment: I have put a wrong link to this post. I edited it.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "the peak of image1 looks like its not from image1"?

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: I don't really understand this question...what do you want to achieve? and arrows-like breadcrumbs for navigation? or what?

Comment: You can't make images that aren't transparent suddenly see-through with CSS. There are many examples of arrow breadcrumb menus available by a simple google search. - http://jsfiddle.net/499nhjb0/5/

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I have put an examlple to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need images here, you can use a css 100% solution with css triangle:

```css
.arrow {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.arrow:before,
.arrow:after{
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 0 25px 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.arrow:before {
    left:0;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}
.arrow:after {
    right:-50px;
}

.arrow-left {
    z-index:1;
    background-color: red;
}
.arrow-left:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
}

.arrow-right {
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.arrow-right:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow arrow-right"></div>
```

Comment: What if he/she wants pictures (not just base colors or gradients) in their arrows ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will rely on this solution. However, I would prefer to use images. Do you thing it is too complicated this way?

Comment: Look my another post solution!

Answer (score 3):

I find a new solution, but not easy to implement. First you need a calculator and know how Math Pythagore is working.

The idea is to have a box with background image and the same image on child, then place the child image at the right then rotate, the difficult part are to place exactly the image to correspond with the background image.

For the separator, i used a rotated square placed between the two arrow.
Then for the last arrow, i used the same way to the first arrow without the before triangle to hide the first part.
All placed in absolute with z-index.

[image]

But finally working with images. Enjoy!

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 136px;
  height: 100px;
}
.arrow-left:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;  
}

.arrow span {
  width:70.71px;
  height:70.71px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: -35px;
}
.arrow span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  right: -40px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.arrow-left {
  background: url(http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/200/100/1) 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 3;
}

.separator {
  left: 95px;
  background: #fff;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.5px;
  z-index:2;
}

.arrow-right {
  background-image: url(http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/200/100/1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="arrow arrow-left">
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/200/100/1" alt="" />
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow-right">
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/200/100/1" alt="" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also can viewed on my codepen : http://codepen.io/pik_at/pen/dPKXWp

Comment: Ahah, you are overcomplicating your life but this is kinda tricky and I like it, +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workable exemple, with over effect and active state : http://jsfiddle.net/jo27axjc/1/

Have Fun !

```
.breadcrumb {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.breadcrumb a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
}
.breadcrumb a:first-child:before {
    left: 14px;
}
.breadcrumb a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.breadcrumb a.active, .breadcrumb a:hover span, .breadcrumb a:hover{
    background: red;
}
.breadcrumb a.active:after, .breadcrumb a:hover:after {
    background: red;
}
.breadcrumb a span{
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    background: blue;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.breadcrumb a.active{
    padding-left:0;
}
.breadcrumb a.active span{
    background:red;
}
.breadcrumb a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    right: -18px;
    width: 36px; 
    height: 36px;
    transform: scale(0.707) rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 1;
    background:blue;
    box-shadow: 
        2px -2px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 
        3px -3px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.breadcrumb a:last-child:after {
    content: none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would prefer to use images. Do you thing it is too complicated with images?

Comment: You can't achive this with img if you want to make them links, with over zones.
with img, the over are going to ovelapping each others sadly

Comment: @Mat: that's true, +1 (You can put a transparent mask over the image and play with pointer-events, though)...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong: your images consist of a big transparent arrow-shaped "hole", that you fill with the background-color, and the parts external to the arrow (the three triangles), that are white:

[image]

And this is what is causing your problems. Example:

```css
.arrow {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-image: url(http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150226/fag7h2u7.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: 125px;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow red"></div>
<div class="arrow blue"></div>
<br>
<div class="arrow red" ></div>
<div class="arrow blue" style="left: -30px;"></div>
<br>
<div class="arrow red" ></div>
<div class="arrow blue" style="left: -30px; z-index: -1;"></div>
```

Solution: **simply invert your approach**, transforming your images into ones consisting of a big coloured arrow, and three transparent triangles at the sides; then you can overlap them whithout overriding the objects below (read: previous and next arrows).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I know my images, i created a second one to get closer to a solution. The thing is the image size and the color can also change, so i would prefer if i had 1-2 different images that work together. I hope i have understood your answer correctly.

Comment: If your images will change, you will link the new images in CSS (and eventually adjust the size), or replace the old image link with the new one, leaving the CSS unchanged. The point is: the *way* you were producing images (image transparent, the rest solid) is wrong; it should be the exact opposite (image solid, the rest transparent). That said, as proven by the other answers, there are several ways to achieve this without using images with pseudo elements (assuming you don't need pictures in your images, nor legacy browser support).

Comment: Also, since I've answered your answer as first, when the other people was still asking clarification on what you needed, and the answer is strictly based on the code you provided, without the assumption that your only need is to have a generic breadcrumb with a completely different code (receiving a downvote as reward :), please consider upvoting the answer, if it helped you understanding the error and finding one (of the possible) solution(s).